# Serilog does not create log files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

Serilog does not create the logfiles - and because of that (I think) nothing is going to be logged.
Due to the target is should be an microservice, I'm using the CQRS pattern.

Here is my Startup.cs

```
private readonly ISession session;
private readonly ILogger logger;

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
  Configuration = configuration;

    var baseDirectory = Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .WriteTo
                    .Logger(lc => lc.Filter
                                    .ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Information || e.Level == LogEventLevel.Debug)
                                    .WriteTo.RollingFile(Path.Combine(baseDirectory, "/Logs/info.log")))
                    .WriteTo
                    .Logger(lc => lc.Filter
                                    .ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Error)
                                    .WriteTo.RollingFile(Path.Combine(baseDirectory, "/Logs/error.log")))

}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  }

   loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
   ...//To shorten this example in Stackoverflow, I've excluded the standard code. But in reality they are of course there
}
```

Here is my Class, in which the logger will be injected by the DI:

```
public MaterialCommandHandler(ISession session, ILogger<MaterialCommandHandler> logger)
{
  this.session = session;
  this.logger = logger;
}
```

and the Handle method, which is located in the MaterialCommandHandler class, in which I want to write something into the log file

```
public async Task Handle(CreateMaterialCommand command)
{
  var material = new Material(command.Id, command.TechDesc, command.Description, command.MaterialClass);
  logger.LogDebug($"{DateTimeOffset.UtcNow} - {nameof(CreateMaterialCommand)} - received for {material} with {nameof(command.TechDesc)} : {command.TechDesc}.");
  await session.Add(material);
  await session.Commit();
  logger.LogDebug($"{DateTimeOffset.UtcNow} - {nameof(CreateMaterialCommand)} - received for {material} with {nameof(command.TechDesc)} : {command.TechDesc}.");
}
```

Anyone an idea, why the files were not be created - and nothing will be logged?

Comment: does `/Logs` exist on the system? Does the process run as a user with write access to `/Logs`? Is there an error?

Comment: @PeteGarafano Yes, the folder exists on the system. It is C:/Logs/ - and I‘m the Administrator of the system, so there should not be any access/authorization problems. Unfortunately there are also no errors - that‘s why I‘m wondering why it does not working

Comment: The code you have shown does not compile. I can't see a call to `CreateLogger()`. Also, for purpose of testing auth\access problems it is probably worth giving `Everyone` modify permissions on the logs folder (only),, just for testing.

Comment: @CalC oh I‘m sorry I‘ve forgotten to copy it here - of course I have it in my code.

Comment: Did you try enabling the self logger, as described in the documentation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing the `.CreateLogger()` statement from the end of your log construction but I think the real problem is your `Path.Combine` statement is probably resulting in an invalid path or a path you're not expecting. `Path.Combine` has some annoying behavior you might not be aware of. Consider the following:

```
Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp", @"Logs\mylog.txt"); // C:\Temp\Logs\mylog.txt
Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp\", @"Logs\mylog.txt"); // C:\Temp\Logs\mylog.txt
Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp\", @"\Logs\mylog.txt"); // \Logs\mylog.txt
Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp", @"\Logs\mylog.txt"); // \Logs\mylog.txt
```

Comment: I have checked it, and yes the problem was Path.Combine..Thanks a lot